# How to show standard deviations along with the values in normal distribution graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I would like to see standard distribution (or cumulative %) along with the values in normal distribution, something like this.

[image]

The following code produces values in X axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
  
vals = np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000)
vals.sort()

mean = np.mean(vals)
sd = np.std(vals)
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(vals, mean, sd)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(vals, pdf, c='blue', marker='.')
ax.set_xlabel("vals", fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel("p", fontsize=10)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='0.55', linestyle='--')
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='0.85', linestyle='--')
ax.minorticks_on()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this will help you: https://gist.github.com/mnguyenngo/3e0695c138c567852cff966c19ea0354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Pygirl for your initial idea of Z score, which suits my purpose. Having said that, highly appreciate your effort on modifying the script with cumulative %, cheers!

Here's what did work for me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(42)

vals = np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000)
vals.sort()

mean = np.mean(vals)
sd = np.std(vals)
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(vals, mean, sd)

zScore = stats.zscore(vals)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(vals, pdf, c='b', marker='.')
ax.set_xlabel("vals", fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel("p", fontsize=10)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='0.5', linestyle='--')


ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.plot(zScore, pdf, c='b', marker='.')
ax2.grid(b=True, which='major', color='r', linestyle='-')
ax2.set_xlabel("zScore", fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
  
vals = np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000)
vals.sort()

na = np.array(vals, dtype='float')


mean = np.mean(vals)
sd = np.std(vals)
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(vals, mean, sd)


fl = True
l = []
l.append(mean)
co = 1
while(fl):
    left = mean-(co*sd)
    l.insert(0, left)
    right = mean+(co*sd)
    l.insert(len(l), right)
    if ((left<=vals[0]) | (right>=vals[-1])):
        fl = False
    co = co +1;
    

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(vals, pdf, c='blue', marker='.')
ax.set_xlabel("vals", fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel("p", fontsize=10)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='0.55', linestyle='--')
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='0.85', linestyle='--')

ax.minorticks_on()
g = lambda x: stats.norm.cdf(x, loc=mean, scale=sd)
for a,b in list(zip(l[1:], l)):
    plt.axvline(a, color='red', label='z=ε')
    plt.axvline(b, color='red', label='z=ε')
    plt.fill_between(vals, pdf, 0, where=((b<=na) | (na<=a)), color='gray')
    plt.text(a-sd, 0.05, "{:.2f}".format((g(a)-g(b))), fontsize=12, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

feel free to edit the code as per your requirements.

[image]